# Override helper.php on mod_related_item

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override

I want to get the related items of an article order by `created` and only show the related items that have the same `catid`.

To accomplish that i must change the `helper.php` code and add this code:

```
$catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); 
if($catid){
    $query->where('a.catid='.(int)$catid);
}
$query->order('a.created DESC');
```

The problem here is, i don't know how to override the `helper.php` on my template. I've already tried to create the file `templates/<template>/html/mod_related_items/helper.php` and copy the core code to there but it didn't work.

How can i accomplish this without editing core code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates can only override template/layout files. You can fork the module or use a plugin like MVC Override https://gruz.ml/en/extensions/mvcoverride.html.